# What is the correct way to plot a dynamically generated list of functions?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate

For example, I want to generate a list of random waves and plot them.

Then I wrote

```
f:=Random[Real]
h:=Floor[f*20]
```

And then

```
Manipulate[Plot[Table[f Sin[h x + h t], {n, 0, 5}], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

But it turned out a mess.

I tried to fix it with

```
a = Table[f Sin[ h x + h t], {n, 0, 5}]
Manipulate[Plot[a, {x, -5, 5}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

But no graph was generated.

Finally I tried

```
a = Table[f Sin[ h x + h t], {n, 0, 5}]
Manipulate[Plot[a /. t -> b, {x, -5, 5}], {b, 0, 10}]
```

This time the graph was correct. But there are still 2 problems:

1. All functions are in the same color.
2. It lags a lot when I tried to manipulate t.

These problems don't exist if you write by hand the list inside plot.

So what is the correct way to solve these problems and get the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used 3 rather than 6 functions for each plot and used a `Frame` rather than `Axes` to reduce the clutter.

```
f := RandomReal[];
h := Floor[f*20];
```

When the `Table` is inside of the `Plot` use `Evaluate`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[
   Table[f Sin[h x + h t], {3}]],
  {x, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1},
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False],
 {{t, 5}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 a = Table[f Sin[h x + h t], {3}];
 Plot[a, {x, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1},
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False],
 {{t, 5}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Similarly, the `ReplaceAll` needs to be in an `Evaluate`

```
a = Table[f Sin[h x + h t], {3}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[a /. t -> b], {x, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1},
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False],
 {{b, 5}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]